# How to solve this java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" based on my code?

Tags: java, runtime, numberformatexception

I write the code for the LeetCode problem Reverse Integer. I cannot find what's wrong with my solution, but when running it in the LeetCode official site, it propagates this runtime error.

```
   class Solution {
    public int reverse(int x) 
    {
        String resultStr = "";
        int result = 0;
        boolean isNegative = false;
        if(x < 0)
        {
            isNegative = true;
        }
        int integer = Math.abs(x);
        int divid = integer;
        while(divid!= 0)
        {
            divid =  divid/10;
            resultStr += integer%10;  
            integer = divid;
        }
        result = Integer.parseInt(resultStr);
        if(isNegative)
        {
            result = 0-result;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check if `resultStr.equals("")` before parsing it to `int`. If `divid` is `0`, `resultStr` will stay empty.

Comment: Good catch. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The final solution for this problem:

```
class Solution {
public int reverse(int x) 
{
    String resultStr = "";
    int result = 0;
    boolean isNegative = false;
    if(x < 0)
    {
        isNegative = true;
    }
    int integer = Math.abs(x);
    int divid = integer;
    while(divid!= 0)
    {
        divid =  divid/10;
        resultStr += integer%10;  
        integer = divid;
    }
    if(resultStr.equals(""))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            result = Integer.parseInt(resultStr); 
            if(isNegative)
            {
                result = 0-result;
            }
            return result;              
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

}